# Even though django-environ is set up correctly, why does Django give the error The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty?

Tags: django, environment-variables

The open source project I'm developing uses Docker to use multiple env files, but I need to run the project without Docker.
Although I set django-environ correctly, I get the error "The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty"
Does anyone have a solution?

I also added this part of the code to the settings

```
import environ

env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../docker/dev/docker.env'))
```

But still it gives the following error

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django-environ` is a good choice for this purpose and you choose a good way to make your variables environment variables.
I think your `settings.py` module should be like the below code snippet:

```py
import environ
import os

env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)

# Set the project base directory
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

# False if not in os.environ because of casting above
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

# Raises Django's ImproperlyConfigured
# exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

# Parse database connection url strings
# like psql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8458/db
DATABASES = {
    # read os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] and raises
    # ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found
    #
    # The db() method is an alias for db_url().
    'default': env.db(),

    # read os.environ['SQLITE_URL']
    'extra': env.db_url(
        'SQLITE_URL',
        default='sqlite:////tmp/my-tmp-sqlite.db'
    )
}

CACHES = {
    # Read os.environ['CACHE_URL'] and raises
    # ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found.
    #
    # The cache() method is an alias for cache_url().
    'default': env.cache(),

    # read os.environ['REDIS_URL']
    'redis': env.cache_url('REDIS_URL')
}
```

The error you've gotten is about missing `SECRET_KEY` in your `.env` file so your `.env` file for above *settings* should have below variables:

```
DEBUG=False
SECRET_KEY=your-secret-key
DATABASE_URL=psql://user:un-githubbedpassword@127.0.0.1:8458/database
SQLITE_URL=sqlite:///my-local-sqlite.db
CACHE_URL=memcache://127.0.0.1:11211,127.0.0.1:11212,127.0.0.1:11213
REDIS_URL=rediscache://127.0.0.1:6379/1?client_class=django_redis.client.DefaultClient&password=ungithubbed-secret
```